# Coupon Code is not initially applied to WooCoomerce Checkout programatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to apply a Custom Coupon Code on WooCommerce Checkout if two Checkboxes are ticked. The Script is barely working - If i load the Checkout Page the Code is applied but the Totals are not calculated correctly. Once i change the Payment Method the Coupon Code works

I expect the Coupon Code applied and the Totals correct if i

- Load the Page with the Checkboxes ticked
- Change the Checkboxes
  without changing the Payment Methods

Here is my Code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','handling_fee', 10, 1 );
function handling_fee() {
    parse_str(WC()->checkout()->get_value('post_data'), $post_data);

    $coupon_code = 'detailer';
    $highest_coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
    $coupon_code_object = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);

    // Get the Highest Percent Amount
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() as $coupon) {
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon);

        if($coupon->amount > $highest_coupon->amount) {
            $highest_coupon = $coupon;
        }
    }

    // If customer is Business Client and Detailer
    if($post_data['billing_business_client'] && $post_data['billing_detailer']) {
        // Add the highest coupon code to Cart
        if(!in_array($highest_coupon->code, WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons())) {
            WC()->cart->apply_coupon( $highest_coupon->code );
            WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
        }
    }
    else if(in_array($coupon_code_object->code, WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons())) {
        WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_tip_script' );
function woocommerce_tip_script() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name="billing_detailer"]', function(){
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
            $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name="billing_business_client"]', function(){
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
        })
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Thanks for your advice!!

Comment: I am guessing, the code is not working initially because your validation is depending on `post_data` which I am guessing is not available in the initial state. I will suggest you use `WC()->checkout->get_value('billing_business_client')` && `WC()->checkout->get_value('billing_detailer')` to get direct value and check if that works or not.

Comment: @VijayHardaha Thanks for your advice, if i use
`WC()->checkout->get_value('billing_business_client')`
I always get the true value with the 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' hook... Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Maybe `WC()->checkout->get_value('billing_business_client')` is the wrong approach. I can't say what is wrong with the code without testing and debugging the values.